# localhost redirected you too many times all on a sudden

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-2.0

We are using grails-2.1.1. We have built a project with this which was running so fine. When I am running my project from intellij today it gives this error `localhost redirected you too many times.` all on a sudden.

I have cleared all my cookies from browser. But no luck. No error at all in intellij console. here is the error below in the browser >>

[image]

Comment: Do you get the same result if you run your app from the console? I ask because you mention that this behavor started when you try running with intelij.

Comment: Have you looked into the requests what gets send and if the header give some clue about the cookies about to be set etc? Does the application use e.g. spring security or any other things that make use of cookies, so you can shrink the problem space? Is the log giving any clues?  Have you tried ramping up the logging (e.g. DEBUG)?

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when Grails tries to login the user but no user exists in the User table in the database.

Make sure that the page you are trying to visit doesn't require special permissions and that you have User/Role/UserRole tables created with proper user information.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was, a user save invalid data in requestmap table.

Comment: How is my answer different than yours? I correctly identified where the problem could be.

Comment: your answer were not so specific in which table the problem can be

Comment: Since I do not have access to the code, I could only tell in general where the problem could be. I did write the User table, if you didn't it. The problem could be very well in the Role and/or the UserRole table. If they do not get populated properly the problem exists.